# How to tell Visual Studio (MSBuild) to copy all files in the folder, including empty folders?

Tags: c#, directory, msbuild, copy, csproj

I have a `Template` folder in the project that should not be compiled or anything but should be included when built so my app can copy it later. The content may include C# files as well. I previously use this declaration to copy everything:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Remove="Template\**\**" />
        <Content Remove="Template\**\**" />
        <Folder Remove="Template\**\**" />
        <None Include="Template\**\**">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

However today I realize it doesn't include **empty folders**. I would like to use a wildcard declaration instead of separate `<Folder Include="..." />` like other articles on SO as the content of `Template` may be changed later and I do not want me or my teammate forget to add it. Is there such declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a flag or declaration or metadata for the `CopyToOutputDirectory` feature that will make it copy empty directories.

The `CopyToOutputDirectory` feature uses the `Copy` task and the `Copy` task doesn't copy empty directories.

There is discussion/feature requests about [MSBuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild) copying empty directories so this may change in the future but it is not available today.

In the general case the question should be asked, does the copied directory structure really need to have empty directories? Can it be acceptable (or made to be acceptable) that an empty directory is not included in the output? For example if the directory structure is consumed by code, can the consuming code be updated to gracefully handle 'missing' directories?

For when empty directories are required, two approaches are:

- Create a custom MSBuild target that statically builds the expected directory structure in the output directory. This target would be straight-forward to implement, it could be a single [`MakeDir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/makedir-task?view=vs-2022) task, but would require maintenance (i.e. changes) whenever the directory structure changes. If changes are infrequent, this may be fine.
- Create a custom MSBuild target that dynamically walks the directory structure and creates matching directories in the output directory. This target would require more effort to implement but won't go 'out of date' when the directory structure is changed.

If these tasks are non-destructive and only add missing directories, they could be run either before or after the `CopyToOutputDirectory` step happens in the build.

If one of these targets is implemented, it would be a good idea to also implement a target that is invoked on a `clean` that removes the directory structure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I have never made a MSBuild task before, maybe this is the perfect opportunity to learn. Btw I don't believe no one else has ever made one, this should be popular enough... As for the question of the empty folder being needed, yes it is needed because it is further used by other apps and not is under my control.

Comment: Targets and tasks are different in MSBuild. You can achieve what you need in a target. Or you could create a custom task and call the task in your target.

Comment: I understand your situation as you have described it but I don't believe that this is a popular need, as strange as that may seem. It's not very robust or resilient for code to fail because a directory that may not be needed (because it can be empty) doesn't exist. That doesn't change the situation that you are working with but I think it does give some explanation for why MSBuild for ~20 years has been fine skipping empty directories.